# Simple web forwarding from one linux box to another (with WOL)

Tags: linux, networking, router, proxy, port-forwarding

Ok I couldn't figure out the exact title for what I am trying to do but here is the gist.

- I have a linux box (call it **Server_A**) that has services running  service at different ports. e.g.
  http://Server_A:80,   http://Server_A:9000 and so on.
  That server sometimes goes to standby (for power savings) and has been setup to wake via WOL
- I have another linux machine (call it **box_B**) that is always on.
- Both machines are connected via ethernet on the same router

What I want to do is as follows:

- I want to be able to make a web request (e.g. via browser) on **box_B** that will wake up **server_A** and forward to the right port. Like some kind of web proxy.

so for example:
client -->  http://box_B/site_1  ---> WOL server_A ---> forward to webpage of http://server_A:8080

client -->  http://box_B/site_2  ---> WOL server_A ---> forward to webpage of http://server_A:9000

Once the forwarding is done to server_A then box_B does not nee to do anything else.

I am not sure if I explained it property, but this sounds like some kind of reverse proxy solution. Can you point me to the right direction?

BTW everything is internal network,  same router, same subnet. No internet

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very good idea ...
You going to need to do some coding ...
You can make a *php https page* on **box_B** to listen and transfer *any post/get request to it from a www* to a command to **server_A**

This is an example of the php:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58985969

and then you add your conditions depending on what payload you receive to execute a shell command with php functions like *exec* or *shell_exec* there are few of those you can use